# html embed tag video events

Tags: javascript, html, video, embed

I am using html embed tag to run my video.But I am facing problem to get its event, I want to call a function when a play or pause event is triggered.
Also I want video is play when I clicked on play button.

I need your help:

My code is below -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
    <body>
        <div class="modal-box">
            <div class="modal-box-content">
                <embed id="video1" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871" width="600" height="600" frameborder="0"></embed>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button id="playButton" style="width: 80px" >Play</button>
        <div >Elapsed Time: <span id="timeDisplay"></span></div>

      <!-- Button width set so overall size doesn't change when we toggle the label -->



       <script>

         var oVideo = document.getElementById("video1");      //video element
         var button = document.getElementById("playButton");
         var display = document.getElementById("timeDisplay");


         //  Capture time changes and display current position
         oVideo.addEventListener("timeupdate", function () {
           display.innerText = oVideo.currentTime.toFixed(2) ;
         }, false);

         button.addEventListener("click", function () {
           //  toggle between play and pause based on the paused property
           if (oVideo.paused) {
             var oInput = document.getElementById('videoFile');   //text box
             if (oInput.value) {
               //  only load a video file when the text field changes
               if (oInput.value != oVideo.src) {
                 oVideo.src = oInput.value;
                 oVideo.load();
               }
               oVideo.playVideo();
             }
           } else {

             oVideo.pauseVideo();
           }
         }, false);

         // Capture the play event and set the button to say pause
         oVideo.addEventListener("onplay", function () {
           button.innerHTML = "Pause";
         }, false);

         // Capture the pause event and set the button to say play
         oVideo.addEventListener("onpause", function () {
           button.innerHTML = "Play";
         }, false);


         </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you know that the content loaded via embed is a HTML page ?

Comment: @akmozo but when I am writing onplay event it is also not working :(

Comment: <embed wmode=transparent allowscriptaccess="always" id="test" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871" width="600" height="600" frameborder="0" onplay="alert('calling');" onclick="alert('hello');"></embed>

Comment: You didn't understand what I meant ! It's impossible to do anything with that HTML page !!! If you want control the video, you have to embed the video itself in a HTML5 video element ( or other controllable player ) not the HTML page embedding that video !!!

Comment: @akmozo - okay but akmozo when I add video tag it does not support my video from vimeo. code is - 
<video id="video1" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871" />

Comment: Of course it will not because the link that you are using a for a HTML page ! You have to get the video link to use it in your page. I don't know, may be they have some API or something like that to get the video URL for embed in external sites.

Answer (score 0):

Problem why your code isn't working is because you're trying to call DOM functions on an embedded video, which isn't going to work.
Fortunately, this can be done with a nice plugin found here: [Vimeo-jQuery-API](https://github.com/jrue/Vimeo-jQuery-API)
Just make sure you use the Vimeo iframe embed and look for the section on API events for your needs. Note, this will only work for embedded Vimeo videos.
 Include the plugin code after Jquery, then you can bind event listeners on the iframe id:

```
$("#myvideo").on("play", function(){
    alert('Playing!');
});

$("#myvideo").on("pause", function(){
    alert('Pausing!');
});
```

Working JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vvemqpvg/1/